# Appcelerator - No space left on device

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I use Appcelerator to develop apps for my job.

Recently, (whilst I have been away on annual leave) our office's server became full due to a new CCTV system. We have been told not to tamper with it and that additional storage has been ordered, but it will not arrive until some time next week.

My problem is that for some reason, appcelerator appears to need space on this network drive to launch. Deleting personal files (to temporarily free up some space) allowed appcelerator to launch, but soon after when I tried to 'Run' an app for testing purposes I got the following error "ENOSPC: no space left on device, write".

I vaguely remember having this issue before when our server became temporarily unavailable. I have never used our server in conjunction with appcelerator so I have no idea why it is attempting to access our server in the first place! If it helps, I have re-installed appcelerator multiple times since the first time this happened many months ago.

My question is, does anyone have any idea how to stop appcelerator from needing our server to function normally?

Thank you for taking the time to read about my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Are you working off a virtual machine on the server or your own stand-alone computer? Given the error message the former makes sense, but in the latter situation that's a really weird error to encounter. You could also check as to where your workspace for your files are in AppC Studio.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I am using a local machine, unfortunately that means that I cannot access it over the weekend but I will check where my workspace is on Monday! I am 99% sure that it is on my C drive but I guess sometimes it's the most obvious things you overlook!

Comment: I checked where my workspace was and as I thought, it was already right in my local documents folder. I've managed to get my boss to clear me some space so I should be okay for the time being now. Thanks again for your help!